# In-App Purchase not working or restoring for some clients

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have been receiving from some of my clients that even they do in app purchase, the product is not loaded. But most of my clients do not have this issue. I was instructing them to do restore operation but that didn't help. The thing is they can restore correctly in other device with same Apple id.

There is no specific device or IOS version and App is not crashing. Just it says restored correctly or purchased correctly, but its not doing it.

It makes me crazy because I tried in many devices and it works correctly for me.

I want to share the code I use for that which may help you to understand issue which I can't.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    NSUInteger count = [response.products count];

    if( count > 0 ) {
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Products Available!");
        [self purchase:validProduct];
    }
    else if(!validProduct){
        NSLog(@"No products available");
        [self hideProgressHud];
        isProgress = NO;

        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"Notice") message:LocalizedString(@"Product is not available now.") preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *cancelBtn = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"OK") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        }];
        [alert addAction:cancelBtn];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)purchase:(SKProduct *)product {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %lu", (unsigned long)queue.transactions.count);
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions){
        if(transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored || transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored){
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
            NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
            [[InAppPurchaseManager sharedManager] savePurchaseItem:productID];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        }
    }
    [self hideProgressHud];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [self hideProgressHud];
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{

    static bool isOnce = false;
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
        if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing) {
            //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
        }
        else if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) {               
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            [self refresh_purchaseBtn];

            return;
        }
        else if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored) {
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
            [self hideProgressHud];
            isProgress = NO;
            //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
            NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
            if ([productID isEqualToString:kPURCHASE_ITEM_TYPE_A] || [productID isEqualToString:kPURCHASE_ITEM_TYPE_B] || [productID isEqualToString:kPURCHASE_ITEM_TYPE_C]) {
                [[InAppPurchaseManager sharedManager] savePurchaseItem:productID];
            }
            else {
                NSArray *arr = [Workout MR_findByAttribute:@"productId" withValue:productID inContext:ApplicationDelegate.managedObjectContext];
                if (arr.count > 0) {
                    Workout *workout = (Workout *)[arr firstObject];
                    workout.state = @"purchased";
                    [ApplicationDelegate.managedObjectContext MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
                }
                [[InAppPurchaseManager sharedManager] savePurchasedReadyProgram:productID];
            }

            if (!isOnce) {
//                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:LocalizedString(@"Notice") message:LocalizedString(@"Purchased Item restored succesfully") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:LocalizedString(@"Ok") otherButtonTitles: nil];
//                [alertView show];   
                isOnce = true;
            }

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            [self refresh_purchaseBtn];
        }
        else if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed) {
            //called when the transaction does not finish
            if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                //the user cancelled the payment
            }
            [self hideProgressHud];
            isProgress = NO;
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look right. In `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` you shouldn't do anything except update your UI if required. This method indicates that restoration is finished, but the actual restoration should be performed by detecting the restoration state in `updatedTransactions` (which you do).  In `updatedTransactions` you are calling `finishTransaction` for the `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` state without actually persisting the purchase.  Essentially the code for `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` and `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` should be the same.

Comment: you mean I should move [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]; in paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished to updatedTransactions?